# DNS issue where all subdomains for Debian linux web server resolve to 127.0.0.1 instead of their proper public IP addresses

Tags: linux, dns, debian, webserver

Using example.com, I have a web server that serves:

```
example.com
www.example.com
```

I have a separate staging server which serves:

```
staging.example.com
```

For some reason, the production server resolves staging.example.com to 127.0.0.1. In fact, all subdomains resolve to 127.0.0.1. I do not have the same problem with the staging server. I.e. when I `curl -I www.example.com` from the staging server, I get back the correct public facing IP address.

My question is, why is this happening and how can I fix it so that the production server correctly resolves DNS for subdomains?

Comment: Your question is not about programming. We have a sister site about Unix&Linux, which may be more appropriate. But we lack many details to answer. What is the DNS configuration? And what it is your computer configuyration? Often we override in `/etc/hosts` domains for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the rest of your hosted zone configuration? For example if you have a record like:
`*.example.com  --> 127.0.0.1`

In your hosted zone, this would cause all unmatched subdomains under example.com to resolve to this address

Comment: Do you mean in `/etc/hosts`?  I have this:  (replaced actual server IP with 1.2.3.4)

127.0.1.1 ip-1.2.3.4.ec2.internal ip-1-2-3-4
127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem turned out to be `Dnsmasq`.

Specifically, setting an address value in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` like so:

```
address=/example.com/127.0.0.1
```

This rule will apply to the domain name as well as **all subdomains**. There is no way to have this rule only apply to the root domain.

My fix was to explicitly list the subdomains here and remove the root domain rule

```
address=/api.example.com/127.0.0.1
address=/anothersubdomain.example.com/127.0.0.1
```